# Integrating MobileAppTracking into Game Maker project

Tags: android, game-maker, mobile-app-tracker

I am trying to integrate MobileAppTracking into a GameMaker project, I am following the [explanation here](https://developers.mobileapptracking.com/android-sdk/) which explains how to do it in an Android project.
And now I am trying to do it in GameMaker project into an extension, so it can work with my game. So here are my problems:

1. What part of the manifest data I need to "Inject" using the GameMaker extension options, this is the example in the site:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>        
<application ... >       
    <receiver android:name="com.mobileapptracker.Tracker">       
        <intent-filter>      
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />       
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

2. Will I be able to initialize the MAT object from GameMaker using a raw java file, like this

```java
public void MATInitialize() {
    MobileAppTracker mobileAppTracker = MobileAppTracker.init(getApplicationContext(), "your_advertiser_ID", "your_conversion_key");
    mobileAppTracker.setReferralSources(this);
    mobileAppTracker.measureSession();
}
```

(sorry cant format the code for some reason)

because in the example, the .init method of MobileAppTracker requires Android context?